# Importance of names 'development' and 'production' in grunt-contrib-less

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

The [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-less) from grunt-contrib-less:

```
less: {
  development: {
    options: {
      paths: ["assets/css"]
    },
    files: {
      "path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"
    }
  },
  production: {
    options: {
      paths: ["assets/css"],
      plugins: [
        new require('less-plugin-autoprefix')({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]}),
        new require('less-plugin-clean-css')(cleanCssOptions)
      ],
      modifyVars: {
        imgPath: '"http://mycdn.com/path/to/images"',
        bgColor: 'red'
      }
    },
    files: {
      "path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"
    }
  }
}
```

It provides two entries in the dictionary for `less`: `development` and `production`.

I don't know what to call these entries, perhaps smth like "sub-tasks for less".

1. Does the naming of these matter?
2. Is it possible to only run one of these. I've tried `$ grunt less development`, but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. The names matter and it's something you configure. These are like more like arguments than sub-tasks. Reference: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task
2. Try `grunt less:development`